# Multi Handle Slider MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am seeking to bind a multi handle slider to my model in MVC. The model looks like this

```
class Foo
{
    public double Lowest{get;set;}
    public double Low {get; set;}
    public double Center {get; set;}
    public double High {get; set;}
    public double Highest {get; set;}
}
```

I want there to be 5 handles on the slider so that it looks something like this
[image: Slider Example from MS Paint]

I don't mind if it binds to hidden fields or visible fields, but the values must be sent with the model on post. I am totally open to plugins, as long as you can demonstrate how they would attain my goals.

**P.S.**
I am using the Razor view syntax, not Web Forms

Comment: Are you using a third party slider?

Comment: I am still investigating which slider to use, or roll my own. The jQueryUI slider seems to only have 2 handles and the ajax controls toolkit one is not easily compatible with MVC

Comment: jQuery UI can do multiple slider handles. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery UI's slider is capable of rendering multiple slider handles. The trick is to ensure you set the "range" property to `false`. Then you can add as many values as you want in the `values` array property as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: false,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 150, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
```

I've thrown together this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eZXtu/) to illustrate.

As far as binding these values to your model is concerned, it should be a straight-forward task to set the values of some hidden elements or visible UI elements to the sliders' values and post these back.